# How to hide header in iframe tag to show reports in visualforce pages

Tags: apex

I'm showing reports in visualforce page by using iframe tag. But in the visualforce page. It is not only showing report, It is showing the headers also. I want to hide the header.

I used:

```
<apex:iframe src="" height="1588px" width="100%"/>
```

And i also did:

`<apex:page sidebar=”false” showheader=”false”>`

Answer (score 3):

In then Iframe src url add `?isdtp=mn`  it will hide the header for you.

Comment: I tried this one but it is still showing header of report.